# Deleting from Database when Date goes over a number that can change

Tags: sql

[image]I have a data base that get entry's from a Internal website Form. What I am trying to do is if I generate a link for 5 day it delete entry after 5 day or if I select 10 day it deletes

So I am trying to fix a code that would Look at two colums and if date is greate than days in another it deletes. I have tried the following could anyone help with and idea of what I have done wrong please.

```
$sql="DELETE FROM DB WHERE creation_date < NOW() - INTERVAL days DAY";
```

creation_date = Has Date and Time in
days = is were it would find how many days I would like to keep it before being deleted.

I got got the the View to delete when I say 10 view it gets deleted.

```
$sql="DELETE FROM DB WHERE show_views >= views";
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: No errors Webpage Loads and Run. Just seems to not do any think. I will take a looks to see if i can get a log.

Comment: I have just uploaded an Image of the data base entry. So I need it to look at column called days then look at creation_date and delete when it hit the 10 days later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try:

```
 $sql="DELETE FROM DB WHERE creation_date < GETDATE() - %s" % daysvariable;
```

With the daysvariable being the int of days?

Comment: Hi Thank you. That unforunyly did not work in may case. And not seeing any error

Comment: Hey, try changing NOW() with GETDATE()